# Trash can icon disappeared after Studio 19.10 upgrade from 19.04

Tags: upgrade, icons, trash, desktop-icons

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10, upgraded from 19.04 and 18.04.3.

It works well, but the TRASH CAN icon is gone from my desktop.  The TRASH app works, but there is no visible icon, which complicates file management.

Why is this?  How can I fix this?

Comment: I eliminated the Firefox reference. BTW: The normal Firefox icon is on the left "Internet" menu. Firefox is running so fine, whatever the way I call it.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the missing TRASH icon, [install](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/) and launch GNOME Tweaks, and turn on the TRASH icon in section 3.  [image: GNOME Tweak Desktop icon choices]

Comment: Even the fact I have installed GNOME Tweaks I don't get the same screen as you get. I don't have any "Desktop" option.